# The image in ToggleButton is not displayed properly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

I'm trying to place an image before text in a `ToggleButton`. Everything is going well. But the image is not displayed properly. I've zoomed the image here so that you can see what I'm talking about. As you can see some parts of the image is not displayed properly.

***The image I'm trying to display***

[image]

***The result***

[image]

***The zoomed result***

[image]

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="ColumnsLayoutMiniIcon" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Main/Resources/dark/images/mini/columns_layout_mini_icon.png"/>
```

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="Border" Width="13" Height="13" Source="{StaticResource ColumnsLayoutMiniIcon}">
                    </Image>
                    <Border x:Name="Content"
                            Padding="10 0 10 0">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                          Margin="-2 -3 0 0"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </Border>                        
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">

                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<RadioButton Content="Plan View"
             GroupName="View"
             Style="{StaticResource BaseToggleButton}"
             Checked="SwitchToPlanView_Selected"
             IsEnabled="{Binding SwitchToModelViewsEnabled}"
             IsChecked="{Binding SwitchToPlanViewSelected}">
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: it's like that one pixel is jumping over O_o. Hope you find an answer to this, very strange!

Comment: @DLeh It is been bugging me for several hours now :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `UseLayoutRounding="true"` to the root of your `Window` element. That will make sure picture snaps to the pixels, and doesn't display weird artifacts.

Comment: @Vahid: had the same problem in 2010, UI designers were pissed that their pictures looked like shit in WPF :-)